# Passing values directly to prepared statement method PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO account 
                            SET accFirstName=?, accLastName=?, accTelephone=?, 
                                accAltTelephone=?, accAddress=?, accCountry=?, 
                                accCity=?, accRegion=?, accPostalCode=?, 
                                accEmail=?, accEmailConfirmed=?, accPassword=?, 
                                accType=?, accStatus='A', accDate=NOW(), 
                                accOrder=".$acctID);
```

Can I pass values directly to `prepare()` whithout binding it, like: `accStatus='A', accDate=NOW(), accOrder=$acctID` ?

Those values are not from user input, no need to talk here about security.

It is a php/mysql correct syntax?

Between, I run the query and the data is saved properly in the DB.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

prepared statements combined with stored procedures have a better performance if the same query is executed multiple times with other data inside it. if that query is only run once per script you might do it as described, but remember the loss in security.

examples can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

your syntax / string for the query without the bindings by prepared statements looks fine.